# Best practice in java to create my own interface instead of existing one in retrofit for example

Tags: java, android, interface, retrofit

I am building the network structure in my android application i one of the things i realized is that i want to do is to create my own interface in my requests class .

i have this method for example :

```
public static void getUserData(String owner, final DataManager.OnDataReceived<Owner> listener) {
    Call<Owner> call = getGitService().getUser(owner);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Owner>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Owner> call, Response<Owner> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Owner> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

now...all my methods respond same way to the call back so why not handle this one time ?

so the way i did it it to create class that implement retrofit Callback interface :

```
private static class callbackHandler implements Callback {

    final DataManager.OnDataReceived listener;

    callbackHandler(DataManager.OnDataReceived listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
        listener.onDataReceived(response.body(), getErrorFromResponse(response));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
        listener.onDataReceived(null, t.toString());
    }
}
```

so now all the request look like this :

```
public static void getUserData(String owner, final DataManager.OnDataReceived<Owner> listener) {
    Call<Owner> call = getGitService().getUser(owner);
    call.enqueue(new callbackHandler(listener));
}
```

much clearer ...

1 . what do you think about this solution ? i had better way to handle all Callback same way  ?
2 . the compiler shout at me that

```
  call.enqueue(new callbackHandler(listener));
```

and

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
    listener.onDataReceived(response.body(), getErrorFromResponse(response));
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    listener.onDataReceived(null, t.toString());
}
```

and my interface :

```
public interface OnDataReceived<T> {
    void onDataReceived(T data, String error);
}
```

is unchecked assignment...i understand what that means but not sure how to fix this ?

**UPDATE : solution for the unchecked**

```
private static class callbackHandler<T> implements Callback<T> {

    final DataManager.OnDataReceived<T> listener;

    callbackHandler(DataManager.OnDataReceived<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        listener.onDataReceived(response.body(), getErrorFromResponse(response));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        listener.onDataReceived(null, t.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what do you think about this solution ?

This is called [the adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). You are adapting one interface (`Callback<Owner>`) to another (`DataManager.OnDataReceived<Owner>`).

If your objective is to be able to replace Retrofit with something else in the future, this sort of adapter is perfectly reasonable. Otherwise, you might consider just having `DataManager.OnDataReceived` extend `Callback` and change your method names to match (e.g., `onDataReceived()` turns into `onResponse()`), to avoid the need for this adapter.

> i understand what that means but not sure how to fix this

`callbackHandler implements Callback` wipes out the Java generics.

If this is only for use with `Owner`, use `callbackHandler implements Callback<Owner>` and have it hold a `DataManager.OnDataReceived<Owner>`. If you plan to use this for multiple model objects (assuming that `Owner` is a model), use `callbackHandler implements Callback<T>` and have it hold a `DataManager.OnDataReceived<T>`.

Comment: Thank you ...and yes this suppose to be generic but the complier still don't like my class , i am adding to my question the OnDataRecevied